# adt use with eclipse

Tags: adt

I'm having trouble getting Eclipse (v3.7.2) and the ADT plugin (v18.0.0) to play together.  I'm attempting to get setup to use RFO BASIC.

Here's an update on how I'm progressing. I uninstalled both Eclipse and the Androide SDK. I then unzipped a new Eclipse installation to C:\Eclipse. Using the Windows .EXE installer, I installed the Android SDK, choosing to install to C:\Android\android-sdk instead of the default C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk.

I downloaded the following platforms:
4.0.3 API 15
4.0 API 14
1.5 API 3

These I unzipped these to the \platform folder of Android. Then I started the SDK Manager and all 3 of these showed up. I "Selected All" and did a "Reload" just to be sure they were being recognized. OK, so far, so good. On to setting up the Eclipse ADT plugin.

Start Eclipse, go to "Help -> Install New Software", click "Add", click on "Archive" button, name it "Android Plugin" and point it to "ADT-18.0.0.zip" which I placed in the C:\Eclipse folder. In the "Available Software" dialog, click on "Developer Tools" and click "Next", accept license agreement, click "Finish". Next came a series of dialog boxes, one of which was titled "Install -> Install Details". It listed the following 4 items:

Android DDMS
Android Development Tools
Android Hierachy Viewer
Android Traceview

Here's where I run into trouble. I select all 4 and the "Next" button remains greyed out and this msg is displayed:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

Now if I UNSELECT Android Development Tools, the dialog allows me to proceed and the other 3 items seem to be installed OK.

If, at this point, I go to "Window -> Preferences", Android **DOES NOT** show up in the left side panel.

Am I still missing a component and if so what??? If not, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong???

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Why do you use old ADT ?